# Showing columns of different attributes from the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with some shift based KG data. Our system every second insert data to db. And if shift is equal to 1, then AKG is increasing. if shift equal to 2, then AKG is removing and BKG is increasing.

Let me show show sample data:

| machinename | AKG | BKG | CKG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R01 | 0 | 0 | 150 |
| R01 | 0 | 140 | 0 |
| R01 | 170 | 0 | 0 |
| R02 | 0 | 0 | 185 |
| R02 | 0 | 145 | 0 |
| R02 | 157 | 0 | 0 |

And so it continues. However, I want the following result.

| machinename | AKG | BKG | CKG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R01 | 170 | 140 | 150 |
| R02 | 157 | 140 | 185 |

Before I forget, I use a code like the one below because data is constantly thrown into the database.

```
WITH ranked_vortex AS 
(
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY machineName ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        vortexTable AS m 
    WHERE 
        shift = '1'
)
SELECT 
    machinename, BKG 
FROM 
    ranked_vortex AS RV 
WHERE 
    rn = 1 
ORDER BY
    LEN(machineName), machineName;
```

This returns me last BKG records for every machine. When I change shift to 0, it gives me AKGs, and for the shift 2 it gives me CKGs. But as I said, I want to combine them for same row without zeros.

I need help, how can I solve this problem. If I forgot something please forgive and let me add.

Answer (score 1):

based on your sample data I guess it is enough

```
 SELECT T.machinename,MAX(T.AKG)AKG, MAX(BKG)AS BKG,MAX(CKG)CKG
 FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 GROUP BY T.machinename
```

Comment: Yes, its a good solution. But there is a problem like that, lets say yesterday at 07:01 program insert the data for CKG, shift 2. And CKG value is 200.  But generally at 07:00, it must insert shift 0.  So I want to see data at 13.09.2022 07:00 between 14.09.2022 06:59, it can shows me CKG is 200. But in real, less then 200kg.

Comment: Because of that I used WITH statement. When I use this code, I'll select every last record for shifts.